# Reactjs TypeError:Cannot read property "city" of undefined

Tags: reactjs, typeerror

i am both new user here and reactjs , i tried to make a basic tour site but get an error; I believe its because of mapping but i cant see what's wrong,
Here is error and codes:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'city' of undefined
The above error occurred in the  component:
    in Tourlist (at App.js:9)
    in div (at

> Blockquote
>   App.js:7)
>       in App (at src/index.js:9)
>
> Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error
>   handling behavior.
>
> ```
>     import React from "react"
> ```
>
> >

```
    import { Tourdata } from "./components/Tourdata"
    import Tourlist from "./components/Tourlist.js"

    class CityTour extends React.Component {


    state={mytours:Tourdata}    

            render(){  const touring=this.state.mytours 

        return(  
        <section>
    {touring.map(item =>{return <Tourlist key={item.id} tourinfo={item}/>} )}


     </section>
     )     }
    }
```

> ```
> export const Tourdata= [{id:1,city:"NewYork",name:"New York museums tour",
> img:"https://images.pexels.com/photos/313782/pexels-photo-313782.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500"
>
> ,info: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusantium, numquam."  }
>
> ,{id:2,city:"London",name:"London royal palace tour",
> img:"https://images.pexels.com/photos/1837591/pexels-photo-1837591.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500"
>
> ,info: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, conse
> ```

ctetur adipisicing elit. Delectus reprehenderit veritatis, expedita reiciendis quia voluptatum." }

```
,{id:3,city:"Istanbul",name:"Istanbul with all aspects",img:"https://images.pexels.com/photos/1549326/pexels-photo-1549326.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500"
,info: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Laudantium, at. Nam, voluptate assumenda!" } 


,{id:4,city:"Sydney",name:"Sydney city coast tour",img:"https://images.pexels.com/photos/1872047/pexels-photo-1872047.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" 
,info:"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nostrum excepturi omnis deleniti. Accusamus." }]  










import React from "react"
import "./tourlist.scss"


class Tourlist extends React.Component{
state={show:false}

    handleIcon=()=>{this.setState({show:!this.state.show})   }

    render(){const {city,name,img,info}=this.props.tourinfo



        return( <section> 
<div className="img-containers">
<i className="fas fa-window-close fa-3x text-success"></i> 
<img src={img} alt="Countryview" />
</div>
<div className="tourinfo">

<h3>{city}</h3>

<h4>{name}</h4>

<i onClick={this.handleIcon} className="fas fa-caret-square-down text-success"></i>
{this.state.show && <p>{info} </p>}

</div>




</section>
    ) 

    }
}

export default Tourlist


import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar.js"
import Tourlist from "./components/Tourlist.js"
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (<div>
     <Navbar />
      <Tourlist />

      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you declared 2 `Tourlist` on your code. As I understand, something is wrong with this block of code.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar.js"
import Tourlist from "./components/Tourlist.js"
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (<div>
     <Navbar />
      <Tourlist />    //change to CityTour

      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

try importing `CityTour` here instead of `Tourlist` because as the error says `city is undefined` means you haven't provided the proper props needed. And according to your code `CityTour` is the component with mapped data component (`Tourlist`), so `CityTour` must be declared somewhere.

Comment: Thanks a lot you saved my next hours,Actually i expected that Tourlist is main file there, because it is getting main information from CityTour which mapping transferred to it.